Show custom fields from custom post type on order confirmation page and email after payment
I have a WordPress custom post type named properties with a post type key of property. This post type has some custom fields:

first name,
surname,
email address,
phone number,
alternative phone number.

Both post type and custom fields are created using the advanced custom field (ACF) plugin.
On the frontend, I have the WooCommerce single product block which displays the details of the product named seller information including the add to basket button.
When the user clicks the add to cart button, I want to check which property the user is viewing and pull the correct contact information of that particular post/property and add this information to the order confirmation when the user has paid for the seller information product.
Here is my related code:
add_filter('woocommerce_add_cart_item_data', 'add_property_seller_info_to_cart', 10, 2);
function add_property_seller_info_to_cart($cart_item_data, $product_id) {
    // Check if the product being added is the 'Seller Information' product with ID 502
    if ($product_id == 502) {
        // Get the current property post being viewed
        if (is_singular('property')) {
            global $post;
            if ($post) {
                $property_id = $post->ID;

                // Get the custom field values for the property seller
                $seller_name = get_field('property_seller_name', $property_id);
                $seller_surname = get_field('property_seller_surname', $property_id);
                $seller_email = get_field('property_seller_email', $property_id);
                $seller_phone = get_field('property_seller_phone', $property_id);
                $seller_alternative_phone = get_field('property_seller_alternative_phone', $property_id);

                // Add the seller information to the cart item data
                $cart_item_data['property_seller_info'] = array(
                    'name' => $seller_name,
                    'surname' => $seller_surname,
                    'email' => $seller_email,
                    'phone' => $seller_phone,
                    'alternative_phone' => $seller_alternative_phone,
                );
            }
        }
    }
    return $cart_item_data;
}

add_action('woocommerce_checkout_create_order_line_item', 'add_property_seller_info_to_order', 10, 4);
function add_property_seller_info_to_order($item, $cart_item_key, $values, $order) {
    if (isset($values['property_seller_info'])) {
        $seller_info = $values['property_seller_info'];
        
        // Add seller information as meta data to the order item
        $item->add_meta_data('Seller First Name', $seller_info['name']);
        $item->add_meta_data('Seller Surname', $seller_info['surname']);
        $item->add_meta_data('Seller Email', $seller_info['email']);
        $item->add_meta_data('Seller Phone', $seller_info['phone']);
        $item->add_meta_data('Seller Alternative Phone', $seller_info['alternative_phone']);
    }
}

add_action('woocommerce_email_order_details', 'add_seller_info_to_order_email', 10, 4);
function add_seller_info_to_order_email($order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email) {
    foreach ($order->get_items() as $item_id => $item) {
        $seller_name = $item->get_meta('Seller First Name');
        $seller_surname = $item->get_meta('Seller Surname');
        $seller_email = $item->get_meta('Seller Email');
        $seller_phone = $item->get_meta('Seller Phone');
        $seller_alternative_phone = $item->get_meta('Seller Alternative Phone');

        if ($seller_name && $seller_surname) {
            echo '<h3>Seller Information</h3>';
            echo '<p>Name: ' . esc_html($seller_name) . ' ' . esc_html($seller_surname) . '</p>';
            echo '<p>Email: ' . esc_html($seller_email) . '</p>';
            echo '<p>Phone: ' . esc_html($seller_phone) . '</p>';
            echo '<p>Alternative Phone: ' . esc_html($seller_alternative_phone) . '</p>';
        }
    }
}

But with my code, it does not display the seller information on both orders and email notifications, I am not sure where the issue is.

So where is the problem with your code? What is missing? As currently, your code displays the seller information in each order item on orders and email notifications, so even your last function is not really needed as you get another time that seller information on email notifications.

Sorry, I forgot to mention that the code does not display the seller information on orders and email notifications, so I am not sure where I am going wrong.

The problem then comes from your first function, that is not retrieving the ACF fields from your custom post type. To check that, you should enable WP_DEBUG as explained in HERE and use error_log() inside your first function. Start checking with error_log( is_singular('property') ? 'TRUE'  : 'FALSE' ); and so on…

Thank you very much, you were right. is_singular('property') returned false and to address this, I used the $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] to get the current page and check if it’s a property post. That worked like a charm. Once again, thank you for your assistance.
